Styles in .razor.css in blazor hybrid doesn't show on emulator windows
Hi wanted to ask how does styles work in blazor hybrid. Becaouse if I want to style one page I add styles to .razor.css . I know .razor.css are scopped styles but should'n it work too?
But when I start my program styles are not rewritten. I tried to add to .razor only  and that is working it showing my changes. There is one option to add everything to gloval app.css or input more .css pages but that would be mess in index.php.
I even tried to add builder.Services.AddBlazorWebView();
How will I see changes on my program in windows emulator with .razor.css?

Well I found out that the problem was somewhere else. I dont know where but when I created a new project styling in .razor.css was good. Then I remember thar I copied some files like wwwroot and Components. But still I would like to know where the problem would be
